# Does List.map guarantee to preserve the sort order of the original list?

Tags: dart

Does List.map guarantee a preserved order of the original list?

I'm parsing a JSON string to Dart objects and trying to do something like:

```dart
var transformedList = someList.map((e) => doStuffWith(e)).toList();
```

... and I'm wondering if `List.map(...)` is guaranteed to preserve the order of the list that is being mapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

The *iteration order* of a list is the index order, from `0` to `list.length - 1`.
The `Iterable.map` operation processes elements in iteration order, and outputs the mapped result in that order, and the `toList` operation creates a new list with the iterated elements in iteration order.

This is [documented](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/List-class.html#:%7E:text=and%20toList.-,Lists%20are%20Iterable,-.%20Iteration%20occurs%20over) as part of the `List` API.

Comment: Citation might be needed.

Comment: Citation added.